# Itk: ImageRegionIterator GetIndex() call makes the program segfault

Tags: c++, itk

I'm iterating over a region of an Ikt::Image. This Image can be different depending on an input of the program. Summarising the main part of the program:

```
//inputMask is an input and contains a label image

typedef typename itk::ImageRegionIterator<TInputImage> InputIteratorType;
std::auto_ptr<InputIteratorType> pIit;
if(someBool)
{
    // here I remove some labeled areas, based on some characteristics
    // ...
    // relabeledMask = result of the evaluations

    InputIteratorType iit(relabeledMask, relabeledMask->GetLargestPossibleRegion());
    pIit.reset(&iit);
}
else
{
    InputIteratorType iit(inputMask, inputMask->GetLargestPossibleRegion());
    pIit.reset(&iit);
}

for (pIit->GoToBegin(); !pIit->IsAtEnd(); ++(*pIit))
{
    if (pIit->Value() > 0)
    {
        typename TInputMask::IndexType seed = pIit->GetIndex();

        // remaining part of the program
        // ...
        //
    }
}
```

Now... this last `for` works only if `someBool` is false. If it's true the program crashes at line `typename TInputMask::IndexType seed = pIit->GetIndex();` with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Moreover if I put this `for` INSIDE the `if(someBool)` (just after `pIit.reset(&iit);`) the program doesn't crash.

As a last note if I save `relabeledImage` as a Nifty file I can see every slide of the volume without problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itk::ImageRegionIterator`, and like, hold a weak pointer to the image

https://itk.org/Doxygen410/html/classitk_1_1WeakPointer.html

thus its likely that your `relabeledImage` got destructed. Another way is to take a reference of the image conditionally:

```
TInputImage::Pointer imageToIterate;
if ( /* something */ )
{
    // do stuff
    theFilter->Update();
    imageToIterate = theFilter->GetOutput();
}else
{
    // do other stuff
}
typedef typename itk::ImageRegionIterator<TInputImage> InputIteratorType;
InputIteratorType iit(imageToIterate,imageToIterate->GetLargestPossibleRegion());
// iterate!
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it had something to do with the image being destroyed, but I was unaware of the weak_pointer problem. I actually solved this by adding a function that contains the creation of the iterator, the last `for` and the remaining part of the code (not posted here). I pass to this function the corresponding label Image in the `if` (relabeled) or in the `else` (original).